# Retrieve JSON Data from PHP

Tags: php

If I pass a ID in the URL the below query is not retrieving data based on the ID. How to retrieve JSON data based upon the ID?

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "testphp";
$password = "1234";
$dbname = "testphp";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$sql = "select * from test where id =? order by count asc";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$arr=array();
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       array_push($arr, $row);
    }
    echo json_encode($arr);
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Where's your `bind_param` statement?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, due to your code's vulenrability to SQL injection, you must change your code like this.

**From**

```
$sql = "select * from test where id = ? order by count asc";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

**To**

```
$sql = $conn->prepare("select * from test where id = ? order by count asc");
$sql->bind_param("i", $_GET["id"]);
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

I am assuming column `id` is an number / integer field. 
More info about parameter binding - http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php